# I have a set of questions about writing a journal paper, how to ask?

Tags: support

I have a set of questions about different aspects of a journal paper (eg. What must be included in an introduction... how to write two papers based on the same model, without repeating yourself in the method section... etc.). What I don't want to do it spam the site with X questions.

What's the best practice for this kind of situation on academia SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you do not expect answers to different questions to considerably overlap, please ask them separately.
  We prefer one question per question here (and I never got why other sites don’t).

  There are [hard restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/255554) that throttle your question rate.
  In particular, if you ask many question at once that are not well received, you may quickly run into a question ban that keeps you from asking questions for a considerable time.
  Therefore:
- Unless things are very urgent, start off with one question and wait a day before asking the next one.
  This is not to avoid spamming the site, but so you can learn from your first question when asking your second one.
  (There is also [a badge](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges/120/curious) for asking questions on separate days.)
- Keep in mind that we cannot assess the content and quality of your research.
  We have to take as given what you tell us about those.

  Also keep in mind that writing conventions strongly depend on the field.
  For an extreme example, an introduction in pure mathematics can be nothing more than “We consider the problem of X.”, while it is a certain desk reject in almost every other field.

Comment: Thanks. I'll start putting together my first question and await feedback on if it needs improvement before I consider other questions!